# JS array key dynamic

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have an api data

```
current: {
  errors: {},
  items: {
     Economy: {}
  }
}
```

Object key "Economy" can be different, for instance "Advance"

and i call it like

```
let current = current.items.Economy
```

or `let current = current.items.Advance`

How can i call it dynamically? 
P.S. My front don't know what key will be return

Comment: What do you mean by “call it dynamically”? Read the value? Call a function? Is there only exactly one key? Have you tried the relevant [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.entries` to get every key and value pair in an object. If `items` only has one such key-value pair, then just select the first entry:

```js
const obj = {
  current: {
    errors: {},
    items: {
      Foo: {data: 'foo data'}
    }
  }
};

const [key, val] = Object.entries(obj.current.items)[0];
console.log(key);
console.log(val);
```

If you don't actually care about the dynamic key name and just want the inner object, use `Object.values` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys(current.items)`.

```js
let current = {
  errors: {},
  items: {
     Economy: {age: 10}
  }
}

let keys = Object.keys(current.items);
let currentVal = current.items[keys[0]];
console.log(currentVal);
```

You can also use `for` loop:

```js
let current = {
  errors: {},
  items: {
     Economy: {age: 10}
  }
}
for(var key in current.items){
  console.log(current.items[key]);
}
```